# Custom Mapping using up-to-date Machine Characteristics

Tags: qiskit, qubit-mapping

I'm working to optimize mappings from virtual to hardware qubits using error and calibration data from the backend. I've implemented my algorithm. When I submit a job, it of course takes 1-5 hours to work its way through the queue. By the time it executes, the data for the backend as changed. Is there support in qiskit to write a custom transpilation pass, send it in with my job, and have it execute when my circuit is at the front of the queue and about to run?

My gut says no since this would allow arbitrary code execution on IBM's systems, but it's worth checking anyways.